# Running Spark on Yarn

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run spark on yarn in quickstart cloudera vm.It already has spark 1.3 and Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.4.0 installed.(I am not using spark-submit since I want to run a different version of spark).

I am able to run spark 1.3 on yarn but get the below error for spark 1.4.

The log shows its running on spark 1.4 but still gives a error on a method which is present in 1.4 and not 1.3. Even the fat jar contains the class files of 1.4.

As far as running in yarn the installed spark version shouldnt matter, but still its running on the other version.

**Hadoop Version:**

```
Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.4.0
Subversion http://github.com/cloudera/hadoop -r c788a14a5de9ecd968d1e2666e8765c5f018c271
Compiled by jenkins on 2015-04-21T19:18Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum cd78f139c66c13ab5cee96e15a629025
This command was run using /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.4.0.jar
```

**Error:**

```
LogType:stderr
Log Upload Time:Tue Oct 20 21:58:56 -0700 2015
LogLength:2334
Log Contents:
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-        1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/var/lib/hadoop-yarn/cache/yarn/nm-local-dir/filecache/10/simple-yarn-app-1.1.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
15/10/20 21:58:50 INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.4.0
15/10/20 21:58:53 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: yarn
15/10/20 21:58:53 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: yarn
15/10/20 21:58:53 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(yarn); users with modify permissions: Set(yarn)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.network.util.JavaUtils.timeStringAsSec(Ljava/lang/String;)J
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeStringAsSeconds(Utils.scala:1027)
at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.getTimeAsSeconds(SparkConf.scala:194)
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:54)
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:1991)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:1982)
at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnvFactory.create(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:245)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv$.create(RpcEnv.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:247)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:188)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:267)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:424)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
at com.hortonworks.simpleyarnapp.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:50)
15/10/20 21:58:53 INFO util.Utils: Shutdown hook called
```

Please help

Comment: Did you deploy Spark's assembly jar for your version of Spark in HDFS?

Comment: No, Basically I am following the below code and changed the Application Master to run a Spark application class.

[link](https://github.com/hortonworks/simple-yarn-app) and [link](https://github.com/Shasidhar/spark-on-yarn)  In this method the spark jar is bundled into fat jar and exported to yarn.

Comment: Are you able to run Spark on YARN with different version now? If not then I can help you there. I am running Spark 1.5.2 on YARN in my cloudera cluster.

Comment: Most of the time when you face java.lang.NoSuchMethodError it is because of a class path conflict. Java class loader takes into consideration the first appearance of a class in the CLASSPATH and ignores the later appearances.  So even if you have included the 1.4 into your fat jar, it might be presented after the spark 1.3 and hence it would be ignored. Could you try to set spark.driver.userClassPathFirst  to true?

Comment: I suggest you to not include spark in your fat jar at all. If you are using maven, just exclude spark by setting the scope to be "compile". I have experienced before dependency hell and trust me you want to avoid that.